# Find a general solution to $y''+3y'+2y=12x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a general solution to $y''+3y'+2y=12x^2$

My working out:
Find the roots
$$y^2+3y+2 = 0 \implies (y+1)(y+2)=0 \\ =c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}$$
Using the method of undetermined coefficients, we have

$$r(x) = 12x^2 \implies y_p = K_2x^2 \\ y_p' = 2K_1x \\ y_p'' = 2K_0$$

Equating the coefficients
$$K_2x^2+6K_1x+4K_0 = 12x^2$$

How do I proceed from here?

I know that if $K_1 = K_0 = 0$ I have $K_2x^2=12x^2$ however I don't know how to get the final answer from here which is $y_h+y_p = c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+6x^2-18x+21$?

Using the additional comment, here's what I have tried:

$y_p = K_2x^2 + K_1x + K_0 \\ y'_p = 2K_2x+K_1 \\ y'' = 2K_2$

$$\implies 2K_2+3(2K_2x+K_1) + 2(K_2x^2+K_1x+K_0) = 12x^2$$
We have that $$12+3K_1+2K_0 = 0 \\ 36x+2K_1=0 \\ \implies K_2 = 6, K_1 = -18, K_0 = 21$$

Comment: Your $y_p$ needs to be $K_2x^2+K_1x+K_0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are 10 seconds away from the solution. Your mistake is assuming the wrong particular solution.

In general for particular solution,

$$
y_p=\sum_{i=0}^n K_nx^n,
$$
where $n$ is the highest order of the polynomial.

$$
y_p=K_2x^2+K_1x+K_0
$$

Now, follow the above $y_p$,

$$
y_p^\prime=2K_2x+K_1\\
y_p^{\prime\prime}=2K_2
$$

Obviously $K_2=6$. We also have $2K_0+3K_1+2K_2=0$. There is one more equation, binding $K_2$ to $K_1$.

I hope this helps

Comment: In general, the degree of $y_p$ may have to be higher than the one of the rhs. This occurs when the standard choice for $y_p$ is also a solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: @PierreCarre Incorporated into the answer! Thanks!